# " php console cache:clear " not working. The command freezes in symfony2 terminal

Tags: symfony, caching, console

I am trying to clean the cache of my application

But once I run the

```
php console cache:clear --env=prod -vvv
```

It stays running... 
The application in the webserver alos stop responding.

I tried to add -vvv but it doesn't show any comments.

At the end I always have to stop the process by tapping Ctrl C

What could be? How could I debug that?

One additional question: how long normally it should take to clean the cache?

Comment: Did you check how big is you `/var/cache/prod` directory? Also you could try with `--no-warmup` option. Maybe it's warming up the cache taking so long.

Comment: you can manually dump it with `rm -rf /var/cache/prod/*` (be careful) and then warm it back up with `php bin/console cache:warmup`.  This isn't going to tell you what's wrong, but it may give you insight as if to wether it's hanging on warmup or not.

Comment: Seems like I saw the exact same question yesterday.  This sort of thing can happen if you change some classes such as commands such that the portions that were cached no longer match the actual class.  In which case removing the actual cache directory is pretty much your only solution.  Looks like the question from yesterday disappeared.  Almost like someone deleted it then maybe asked it again.

Comment: @dragoste The cache has 36MB in the prod and 16MB in the dev.

But it seems that not doing warmup is working

Comment: Check that the user that you use when you run the command has the access to Read & Write on the cache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what it was.

I was using the smallest type of instance of the Amazon servers.

Apparently this command used too much memory and system started to collapse.

After some days the server simply stopped because of lack of memory when I was doing this command. 
I changed the instance to a bigger one and the problem never appeared again.